# Distance between two circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

[image]

See image. In situation like this. Is AE and EC always equal. if no then in which cases are the two lines equal.

Comment: AE is equal to EC if and only if the two circles have the same radius.

Comment: can u tell me why is this happening ?

Comment: You have a downvote because you didn’t show your work. Before you get a more detailed answer, you should write your attempt at a solution or at least your thoughts : ) that way we know how to help you.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for the response. I was doing questions about intersections on circles and in the textbook sometimes they took it as equal and sometimes not. I could not connect the dots that they are taking it the same when the radius are equal.

I am still not completely sure why are they equal. Do the two triangles get congruent when the radius are equal ?

Comment: When the circles have the same radius, you get four congruent right-angled triangles.  If not, then not.

Comment: Thanks. I get it now. All the right angle triangle are congruent by RHS when radii are equal and hence AE and EC must be equal by cpct.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not equal in general. They are only equal if the circles have the same radius. If the circles do have the same radius, you can prove that the triangles $\triangle AED$ and $\triangle CED$ are congruent.

If they are congruent then $AE= EC$. The congruence requires $AB = CB$, so the two radiuses have to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Since $AB=AD$ and $CB=CD$, we obtain $BE=ED$ and if you want that also $AE=EC$ then $ABCD$ would be parallelogram, which says $AB=CD.$